# ASP.NET Core MVC User identification

Tags: asp.net, authentication, asp.net-core-mvc

What is the way to do the aboslute same app BUT with user authentication? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/?view=aspnetcore-2.1
If I just select the user authentication in the beginning, the migrations get messed up and MvcMovie link remains unresponsive.
Thanks!

Comment: Here's a place to start: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/?view=aspnetcore-2.1

Answer (score 0):

Try to read this [blog from Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=visual-studio%2Caspnetcore2x). This will help you start how to implement Identity and Authentication